# How to change the kernel in the ubuntu live installer?

Tags: system-installation, kernel, live-usb, security, compiling

I'm having a SSD problem which was fixed in a new kernel, so I need to use this kernel to install Ubuntu. Without this custom kernel the installation fails 90% of the time I try to install Ubuntu, giving I/O errors.

Is it possible to download the ubuntu installer, change its kernel and write it to a pen drive to install ubuntu? How to do it?

I know that there are .deb kernels to download. Is it possible with .deb ones? How to do it with a binary kernel also?

**UPDATE**:

I tried to replace vmlinuz on the ISO file by my own but it won't even boot.

Comment: See:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: On my ubuntu iso I see the files casper/vmlinuz.efi and casper/initrd.lz. I know how to get vmlinuz, but what about initrd? As I've read, I just need to replace vmlinuz and initrd. Am I right?

Comment: What kernel version works with your SSD? And what is your SSD make / model? What version of Ubuntu are you using including suffix, ie 16.04.1, 16.04.3, etc.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix right now no kernel works, I have to compile my own with the pathces made (they're going to enter 4.16.something soon). My SSD is from Samsung. I believed you already tried to help me with this known SSD problem. After lots of tests, a guy in launchpad forum made a fix that worked. You can see the thread here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1746340. While it' easy to replace a kernel after the system is installed, I'm having trouble installing a fresh system because the kernel of the live pen drive is not patched

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I remember bits now. You had a different screen name back then. Razer Blade with Samsung PM961. I have the Samsung Pro 960 that runs with no problems. You were working fine for months on an older kernel version. No luck using the older version again I guess? I'm not sure exactly how but could install Live USB to another USB and then upgrade the kernel there? Then copy the USB to the NVMe using `dd`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix even the older linux had installation problems, but once I got it to work, no problems would happend while running the system. The USB is a good idea, but how to dd to the SSD? Maybe with the older ubuntu? (which also have installation problems)